# what kind of edits should be done?

Tags: discussion, editing

I have seen [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/what-does-shahid-mean) and I'm kinda surprised from the Edit. The Edit is bigger than the original question. What if the OP did not mean that and he/she simply meant what was asked in the original question?

What is recommended for edits? is the edit mentioned in the question above a good edit or bad edit?

Comment: I just saw the edit. In my mind, it changed the original question too much.

Answer (score 4):

> What is recommended for edits?

[Anything that substantially improves the post:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/)

> **If you are going to edit a post, make sure you’re substantively improving it.** Avoid making isolated, trivial edits, as they are the source of much friction. For example, don’t bother changing “its” to “it’s” unless you have several other edits to make in the same post. There has to be a legitimate case that your edit made multiple changes transforming the post from good to great — or at least substantively improving it.
>   (Except when you happen to be editing that rare “perfect except for this one misspelled word” post. This is obviously OK to edit. In my experience, the type of posts that really cry out for editing need a lot of editing to be whipped into shape.)

So don't ever be afraid of doing *too much* - worry about not doing enough!

If you see a poor edit, fix it - by editing! - or roll it back. Post owners are notified of edits, and can roll back changes they don't like with a single click (there's a "rollback" option under the post for owners after someone else has edited it).

Comment: you did mention about edits that changes the point of the original question...

Comment: If the edit is unhelpful or incorrect, fix it or roll it back, @HaLaBi. Don't disrespect the original author, but don't treat his words as sacred. Askers often struggle to effectively express the problem they're trying to solve - helping them accomplish this is an act of kindness. But if you fail, or they simply don't appreciate your efforts, then they can roll it back and you should move on.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of edits do happen on SE. We human are erroneous and sometimes tend to interpret something in the wrong way & and thus add stuff to questions that we think are related to the questions.

These types of edits are sometimes meant [just for fun (see the second revision)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/87660/revisions) , or are caused due to wrong interpretation or are deliberately done (i have seen people add in their own views to the question).

**Things that can be done**

- post a comment to ask the OP if the edit means the same thing what he intends. If yes then forget about the question or else tell the OP to rollback
- If you have editing rights & you feel the edit is blatantly wrong then edit it out yourself.
- if you don't have edit rights flag it for mod review.

---

My opinion about the question is that it seems to be a case where the editor has misinterpreted the question. The edit seems to be wrong IMO

Comment: Same opinion here.. I think it is wrong..